# Position div absolutely inside table cell in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'd like to position absolute element inside table cell relative to it. It works well on all browsers except IE.
It seems that even though cell is properly rendered, relative dimensions in css aren't.
Below is simplified example illustrating what's wrong.

```css
table {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.float {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  bottom: 25%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="float"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

Actual result:

[image: Actual result]

Any clue how to tackle that?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e6tc2qk5/6/

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `table`? You can achieve this with `flex` and it'll be less painfull.

Comment: I actually try to do that in Ext JS grid, so I'm limited when it comes to changing outer markup.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap that div by another div like this

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="float"></div>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
.float {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  bottom: 25%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qn0dwohn/28/

Comment: As it turned out, by using fixed dimensions I accidentaly made it easier to fix. In real life I don't have fixed row height, and wrap doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/e6tc2qk5/16/

Answer (score 0):

just change css of td

```
td {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 100%; // Modified
  height: 100%; // Modified
  display: flex; // Added css
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.